# Python : store data in file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to store the jsonas text file , I am able to print the file but am not able to store the file and also the o/p is coming wiht unicode charatcer.

PFB code.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
with open('20150827_abc_json') as data_file:
    f=open("file.txt","wb")
    f.write(data=json.load(data_file))
    print (data)>f
    f.close()
```

When i execute it , the file gets created but its of zero byte and also how can i get rid of unicode character and also store the output.

o/p

```
u'Louisiana', u'city': u'New Olreans'
```

Comment: You simply copy the content of one file to another ? Why not just copy it ?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen at `print (data)>f` because 1) data isn't defined and 2) you are printing a greater than comparison, not `f.write(data)`

Answer (score 2):

To serialize JSON to file you should use `json.dump` function. Try to use following code

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
with open('20150827_abc_json') as data_file, open('file.txt','w') as f:
    data=json.load(data_file)
    print data
    json.dump(data,f)
```

Comment: You could add `f` to the `with` statement by adding a comma

Answer (score 0):

the `print` syntax is wrong, you put only a single `>` while there should be two of them `>>`.
in python 3 (or python2 if you `from __future__ import print_function`) you can also write, in a more explicit way:

```
print("blah blah", file=yourfile)
```

I would also suggest to use a context manager for both files:

```
with open('20150827_abc_json') as data_file:
    with open("file.txt","wb") as file:
        ...
```

otherwise you risk that an error will leave you destination file pending.